# ionic APN localized formatted strings

Tags: ionic-framework, localization, apple-push-notifications

I was looking for a way to implement the localized formatted strings system for APNS for Ionic in the way as described in this documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html

Does it exist any plugin or documentation to achieve this? I could not find any detailed information. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?